# Assigning JSON text to a string field in Ansible

Tags: json, kubernetes, ansible, yaml, configmap

I am using Ansible with Kubernetes to apply yaml files / config maps.

I want to set the value of a particular field to be a string.  The string will be JSON text, unrelated to the structure of the yaml/config map.

I can do this:

```
- name: Change a field in the ConfigMap (this will be a PATCH request)
  k8s:
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: ConfigMap
      metadata:
        name: "test"
        namespace: test
      data:
        hello: '[{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}]'
```

Which works with single quotes.

With double quotes, it doesn't work.  "Syntax Error while loading YAML.".  I'm guessing it is trying to parse the contents of the JSON with double quotes.

Here's the problem.  I want to use a variable which contains a JSON string, and do the same thing.

Let's say I do this:

```
- name: Set a name variable for this example
  set_fact:
    var: '[{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}]'

- name: Change a field in the ConfigMap (this will be a PATCH request)
  k8s:
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: ConfigMap
      metadata:
        name: "test"
        namespace: test
      data:
        hello: '{{ var }}'
```

Whether I use single quotes or double quotes, this blows up.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error": 422, "msg": "Failed to patch object: b'{\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\" \\\\\"\\\\\" is invalid: patch: Invalid value: \\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"apiVersion\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"v1\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"data\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"extensions\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"extension_point_id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"service_instance_details\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"extension_name\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"custom_instance_details\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"match_instance_id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"532\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"details\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"custom_sections\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"section_key\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"nodessection\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"title\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Configuration\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"rows\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Number of nodes\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Cores per node\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Memory (GiB) per node\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}]},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"section_key\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"storagesection\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"title\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Storage\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"rows\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Storage class\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Size\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}]},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"section_key\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"usersection\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"title\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Credential\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"rows\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Ops Manager user\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"actions\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copyuser\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"icon\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"on_click\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"href_url\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"href_target\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}}]},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Password\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"actions\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"showpassword\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"show\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copypassword\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}]},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Replica set connection\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"updatedValue\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"actions\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copyreplica\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"icon\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"on_click\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"href_url\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"href_target\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}}]}]}]}}]\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"hello\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"age\\\\\\\\\\\\\":31,\\\\\\\\\\\\\"city\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"New York\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"name\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"John\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}]},\\\\\\\\\\\\\"kind\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"ConfigMap\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"metadata\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"annotations\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"apiVersion\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"v1\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"data\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"extensions\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n {\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"extension_point_id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"service_instance_details\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"extension_name\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"custom_instance_details\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"match_instance_id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"532\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"details\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n  {\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"custom_sections\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n     {\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n      \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"section_key\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"nodessection\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n      \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"title\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Configuration\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n      \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"rows\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Number of nodes\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n            { \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Cores per node\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n            { \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Memory (GiB) per node\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n           ]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n     },\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n     {\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n      \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"section_key\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"storagesection\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n      \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"title\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Storage\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n      \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"rows\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Storage class\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n            { \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Size\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\", d\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copyuser\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"icon\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"on_click\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": {\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"href_url\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"href_target\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                  }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n               ]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n            },\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n            { \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Password\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n              \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n              \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"actions\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": [\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                {\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"showpassword\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"show\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                },\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                {\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copypassword\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n               ]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n            },\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n            { \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Replica set connection\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n               \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"jdbc:ibm\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n               \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"actions\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": [\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n               {\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copyreplica\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"label\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"icon\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"copy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"on_click\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": {\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"href_url\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"href_target\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n                }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n              }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n            ]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n            }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n           ]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n     }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n   ]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n  }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n }\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"kind\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"ConfigMap\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"metadata\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"annotations\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{},\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"labels\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"icpdata_addon\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"true\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"name\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test-details\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"namespace\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"prasa\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},\\\\\\\\\\\\\"creationTimestamp\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2021-04-28T02:46:43Z\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"labels\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"icpdata_addon\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"true\\\\\\\\\\\\\"},\\\\\\\\\\\\\"managedFields\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"manager\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"oc\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"operation\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Update\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"apiVersion\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"v1\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2021-04-28T15:44:10Z\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"fieldsType\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"FieldsV1\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"fieldsV1\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"f:metadata\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"f:annotations\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\".\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{},\\\\\\\\\\\\\"f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{}},\\\\\\\\\\\\\"f:labels\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\".\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{},\\\\\\\\\\\\\"f:icpdata_addon\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{}}}}},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"manager\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"kubectl\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"operation\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Update\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"apiVersion\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"v1\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2021-04-28T16:14:58Z\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"fieldsType\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"FieldsV1\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"fieldsV1\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"f:data\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\".\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{},\\\\\\\\\\\\\"f:extensions\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{}}}},{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"manager\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"OpenAPI-Generator\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"operation\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Update\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"apiVersion\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"v1\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2021-04-28T16:25:35Z\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"fieldsType\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"FieldsV1\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"fieldsV1\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"f:data\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\"f:hello\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{}}}}],\\\\\\\\\\\\\"name\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"test-details\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"namespace\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"prasa\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"resourceVersion\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"434431\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"uid\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"c5ea7b6a-94b0-40b7-b171-dc9fcc23e0f2\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}}\\\\\": v1.ConfigMap.Data: ReadString: expects \\\\\" or n, but found [, error found in #10 byte of ...|,\\\\\"hello\\\\\":[{\\\\\"age\\\\\":31,|..., bigger context ...|l\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\"href_target\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}}]}]}]}}]\\\\\",\\\\\"hello\\\\\":[{\\\\\"age\\\\\":31,\\\\\"city\\\\\":\\\\\"New York\\\\\",\\\\\"name\\\\\":\\\\\"John\\\\\"}]},\\\\\"kind|...\",\"field\":\"patch\"}]},\"code\":422}\\n'", "reason": "Unprocessable Entity", "status": 422}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: *With double quotes, it doesn't work* > it would if you escaped the double quotes within the value. Anyway, the error message is not complete, please edit the question to show the complete error message.

Comment: Okay, I updated the error.  What would be the best way to escape the quotes in Ansible?

Comment: Hmm the error message does not seem to correspond to your code. Judging by the amount of backslashes, it's obviously some escaping issue. I suggest trying `{{ var | to_yaml }}` (without surrounding single quotes) since when `var` is a string, that will quote it properly for inclusion as value in YAML.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that, and your code works for me. You need to use single quotes, because the single code is used as a delimiter. Insde the string you cannot use the single quote again, it would mean, the string end is reached. The same with double quotes. If you use them as a delimiter, inside the string you cannot use it again (or you need to escape the double quote inside the string with `\"`

Another option: instead of using a string in `var` you could just create a dictionary and inject it.

```
- name: Set a name variable for this example
  set_fact:
    var:
      - name: "John"
        age: 31
        city: "New York"

- name: "Change a field in the ConfigMap (this will be a PATCH request)"
  k8s:
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: ConfigMap
      metadata:
        name: "test"
        namespace: test
      data:
        hello: "{{ var }}"
```